# How to get max of group by query

Tags: hive, cqlsh

Here is my dataset:

```
00000000040112    2702      00000000040112  AVAILABLE       1566921227223   -6.0    LB
00000000040112    2702      00000000040112  AVAILABLE       1566921247222   -9.0    LB
00030400791888    6065      00030400791888  AVAILABLE       1566919357992   45.0    EA
00030400791888    6065      00030400791888  AVAILABLE       1566919547809   72.0    EA
```

I am trying to get the max from each group, so based on the above data the expected result would be like this:

```
00000000040112  2702    00000000040112  AVAILABLE       1566921247222   -9.0    LB 
00030400791888  6065    00030400791888  AVAILABLE       1566919547809   72.0    EA
```

My query which does not produce the correct result is:

```
select  
  primegtin, nodeid, gtin, inventory_state, 
  max(last_updated_time), 
  quantity_by_gtin, quantity_uom 
from pit_by_prime_gtin 
where 
  year=2019 and month =8 and day =27 and hour=15 
group by 
  primegtin, nodeid, gtin, inventory_state, 
  last_updated_time, 
  quantity_by_gtin, quantity_uom ;
```

What could be wrong with it?

Comment: Hi Sumith - Little unclear, Could you please add column names. Also, What output you are getting with your query

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove columns, that you are aggregating by from `group by` clause.

In your example it should probably be something like:

```sql
select  
  primegtin, nodeid, gtin, inventory_state, 
  max(last_updated_time), 
  max(quantity_by_gtin), quantity_uom 
from pit_by_prime_gtin 
where 
  year=2019 and month =8 and day =27 and hour=15 
group by 
  primegtin, nodeid, gtin, inventory_state, 
  quantity_uom ;
```